What action should be done to questions in different language
While reviewing the questions, I came across questions that are asked in different languages other than English like this. Since AskUbuntu is an English-only platform, we can let the OP know that the question should be asked in English. If the person didn't respond to that, should we do some other action to that question?

Vote as unclear or Needs Details.  In very rare circumstances I will put things into a Google Translate tool and translate when it's clear what happens, but that's extremely rare.  Easier to close and say "Ask Ubuntu is an English Only website, if you do not understand English, please use a translation service such as Google Translate for your question."

Vote to close as unclear - its said in many places that the site is english only. Let them know as such in comments if you feel it'll help, some folks even google translate that.
Its up to the user to take the advice and try to post in english
